# Are questions about hiring QA engineers appropriate?

Tags: discussion, questions

I've had a lot of trouble finding good QA engineers — this is kinda a burning question for me, I need to hire someone right now!

And if the answer is no, I'd really appreciate some suggestions about where I *can* discuss this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've seen at least one "how to interview QA" question, so I'd think they could be okay.  However, you'll want to be sure that you don't run afoul of the 'no overly local / overly specific questions' subjective guideline.  What questions are you considering?  You could probably get a good guess about how they will go over if you post them here first.

Answer (score 0):

Need to hire someone right now, eh? You willing to let them telecommute? :-D

In all honest, absolutely. Stack overflow used to allow them until Programmers.SE came along, which is where you find them now.

It's also worth noting that we as a community decide if something is appropriate. That's the beauty behind the beta.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the question is: are your questions specifically about the challenges/problems in hiring *testers*, or are they more generally about difficulties in hiring new staff?

I think there are definitely challenges specific to hiring testers in particular: the huge number of ["oblivious" candidates](http://redcanary.mypublicsquare.com/view/hiring-software), the problem with getting HR to sign off on adequate salaries for people who essentially specialise in being great generalists, recruiters tendency to obsess on tools because they haven't a clue what a tester actually does, and so on. So there's plenty of scope for very much on-topic hiring questions.